# Что делать если ajax запрос не отрабатывает . на короткой ссылке?

Tags: php, ajax, october

Возникла следующая проблема: в шапке кнопке висит запрос - и он работает везде, кроме главной страницы "/", если ссылка имеет хоть какой-то префикс, то всё работает отлично.

Почему возникает такая проблема и как ее решить?

Comment: показать код, написать какая ошибка происходит... телепаты поувольнялись :)

Answer (score -2):

Возможно, в OctoberCMS не определен маршрут для главной страницы "/". Нужно добавить маршрут для главной страницы в файле роутера OctoberCMS.